# Laravel 5.4 task scheduler not running on windows

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

I've to schedule a task in laravel 5.4. I'm using Xampp (php 7)

I'm running below command and adding a log message. But it is not running **everyMinute()**.

It only run first time when I run this command.

**php artisan schedule:run**

*Output: Running scheduled command: "E:\Xampp\php\php.exe" "artisan" send:sms > "NUL" 2>&1*

That's kernel file:[image: Kernal.php]

[image: sendSMS.php]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a .bat file for that

```
smssend.bat
```

and code is

```
cls 
 cd C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectName 
 php artisan schedule:run dir
```

then add a task in scheduler in windows. it will run this .bat script after time you specified.

Comment: Thanks brother, You solution really helped me. :-) 100/100 (Y)